# Why is my street address not listed when I convert my Careers 2.0 CV to PDF?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, export

I've added my email, street address and phone number to my Careers 2.0 profile.  As expected, [my public profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jericson) shows just my city.  When I export to PDF, the email address, phone number and city are included as they should be.  But my street address is not.

According to the footnote when editing my contact information:

> † = street address, phone and email are only shown to employers you approve

Presumably there's some way to approve showing these items if an employer were to contact me.  But they should also be available when I export my resume.  I can control whether the phone and email are included in the PDF.  But when I check the box to include my Address, only the city gets inserted.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good way of automatically adding a properly formatted full address in there - presumably you'd want the zip/postcode too? Also I'm struggling to understand why you'd need or want to include your full address. I'm assuming nobody these days is going to reply to your job application by sending you a letter?

Comment: @Alex Warren: My use case might be atypical. I gave my resume to my previous employer so they would know what I'm up to. Since the checkbox for "address" was there and since I have no reason to conceal that information from them (they already have it), I figured I'd see what happens. It seems odd to ask for this information if it really serves no purpose. Some jobs (especially those that require a background check) will want to know an address. Having a fixed address might also be something a job seeker would want to signal. Perhaps the simplest fix is to rename the option: City.